# append element in jQuery, keeping original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jQuery interface, where I need to drag elements from one DIV onto a snappable grid in another DIV. Is there a way to append the dragged element to the target DIV (grid), while maintaining it's dragged position? The reason is that the target is in a scrollable area, and needs to be scrolled with the dragged item, right now the dragged item floats on top and doesnt make much sense.

I have already ruled out sortable for other reasons, so am hoping there is either a way to do this with draggable, or to change the position of the draggable item upon scrolling the grid.

Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was trivial:

```
offset = $element.offset();
$grid.append($element);
$element.offset(offset);
```